# Why is my Angular http service unit test not failing?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, angular-httpclient

Hi can anyone tell me why this service test is always passing when it should fail?
I am using Jest if that matters.
The data is 1 object in an array but the test expects 5 and still passes! (The console log does get hit and returns the data);
I have been unable to trigger the expect calls in the subscribe and I do not understand why.

The console log is working, but the expect is not.
I must be doing something really dumb, but not sure what.
Can anyone explain what is wrong?

```
import { TestBed, inject, getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpTestingController, HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { DataHandlerService } from './data-handler.service';

describe('DataHandlerService', () => {
    let injector: TestBed;
    let service: DataHandlerService;
    let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  
    beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
        providers: [DataHandlerService]
      });
  
      injector = getTestBed();
      httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
      service = TestBed.get(DataHandlerService);
    });
  
    afterEach(() => {
      httpMock.verify();
    });
  
    it('should be created', () => {
      service = TestBed.get(DataHandlerService);
      expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    });
  
  
    
    describe('getData()', () => {
      it('should trigger call', () => {
        
        const mockEvt = [{  
          audio: "N",
          city: "Madrid",
          country: "Spain",
          date: "1930-01-01",
        }];
    
        service.getData('/test').subscribe(evtData => {
          console.log('CALLING ..... ', evtData);
          expect(evtData.length).toEqual(5);
          expect(evtData[0].country).toBe('France');
        });
        
        const req = httpMock.expectOne("/test");
        expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET');
        req.flush(mockEvt);
      });
  
    });
  });
```

This is the service I am testing. It is basic right now.
Will add more details after the core test is working.

```
  @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })
  export class DataHandlerService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  
    getData(urlToFetch: string): Observable<any[]> {
      return this.http.get<any[]>(urlToFetch);   
    }
  }
```

Comment: from where are you reading `evtData` ?

Comment: evtData is the returned data from the service response.

Comment: You should be using the done callback at the end of the subscription code, 'req.flush(mockEvt);done();'

Comment: I applied the done() to the it() and it did not work - failed tests still pass.
it('should trigger call', (done) => {  
/// blah blah
req.flush(mockEvt);done();
});

Comment: With async then done() causes error.
it('should trigger call', async((done) => {
      /// blah blah 
req.flush(mockEvt);done();
}));
error :   TypeError: done is not a function

Comment: Without done() in the async() then the tests run correctly. 
it('should trigger call', async(() => { /// blah blah req.flush(mockEvt); }));
Test fails as expected.
expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: 5
    Received: 1

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm … looks like if I use async() without done() then the tests run as I expect.

```
it('should trigger call’,  async(() => {
    //// test info here
   //// means the subscribe is running correctly and the expects get triggered
}));
```

Comment: Maybe you should add this to your question, I don't think it's answering what you asked :)